# Bio.Application.ApplicationError: Non-zero return code -10

Tags: python, biopython

I am trying to run `Muscle` using `Biopython` wrapper `MuscleCommandline` in PyCharm. `Muscle` is in my PATH so I do not specify the binary. I work with `stdout` that I will then write into a file. The input file are 4 sequences in a fasta format.

```
from Bio.Align.Applications import MuscleCommandline

in_filename = /Volumes/DamianEx_2/Data/Results-10-16-2021-19-07/Cenpo/SPICILEGUS_genome/Fasta/above_threshold/MSA/to_align_rev_comp_QGOO01000298.1__rev.fasta
cline = MuscleCommandline(input=in_filename)
stdout, stderr = cline()
```

I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/damian/PycharmProjects/freeda_2.0/freeda/msa_aligner.py", line 56, in run_msa
    stdout, stderr = cline()
  File "/Users/damian/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Bio/Application/__init__.py", line 569, in __call__
    raise ApplicationError(return_code, str(self), stdout_str, stderr_str)
Bio.Application.ApplicationError: Non-zero return code -10 from 'muscle -in /Volumes/DamianEx_2/Data/Results-10-16-2021-20-20/Cenpo/SPICILEGUS_genome/Fasta/above_threshold/MSA/to_align_rev_comp_QGOO01000298.1__rev.fasta', message 'MUSCLE v3.8.1551 by Robert C. Edgar'
```

The input is quite long but it does not complain when I run it using `MafftCommandline` wrapper.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Muscle is an outdated multiple sequence aligner, I would stick with Mafft that you have working

Comment: That is true. I was hoping to cross-check my results using an alternative aligner though. I also tried ClustalW wrapper in Biopython but it doesn't seem to be working for me either. I will put some more effort into troubleshooting though. I was hoping that somebody might know what "code -10" means in this instance.